# Remove browser from focus assist trigger list

Tags: windows-10, focus

I once tried to see if I could use the game recording capability of the Windows 10 Xbox Game Bar to record a screencast. To do that I told Windows that my Chrome is a game. (It didn't really work that way, because it only recorded chrome and I needed other programs as well in the screencast)

Ever since I did that, every time I focus Chrome Windows turns on focus assist:

[image]

I turn it off, click back on chrome, and it is on again. Of course, I could just turn off `When I'm playing a game` in *Settings -> System -> Focus assist*, but I want to keep the feature for actual games.

How can I remove Chrome from that "this is a game" list?

I don't see anything about that in:

- Settings -> System -> Focus assist
- Settings -> Gaming -> *
- Win+G -> Preferences

Installed version of Windows 10: Enterprise 1903 (18362.239)